# How to find the set of linearly independent vectors $(x,y,z,t)$ satisfying $x+2y-3z-t = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I can use brute force and re-check my set of linearly independent vectors $(x,y,z,t)$ that satisfies $x+2y-3x-t= 0$. But I would like to use the concept of nullspace and basis to find out this. What would be the way to go?

Comment: Linearly dependent from what? Do you want to generate all possible vectors that satisfy your equation?

Comment: If there is a linear combination of your vectors giving the zero vector, *by definition* they are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Why does $\{(2,-1,0,0),(-3,0,-1,0),(-t,0,0,-1)\}$ work?

Comment: I still don't understand...

Comment: Example for the second vector: $1\cdot(-3)+2\cdot0-3\cdot(-1)-t\cdot 0$ equals ...

Comment: Oh.. I now got it. Thanks.